# Will only Xubuntu be faster than dualbooting with Windows 8?

Tags: performance

I have installed Xubuntu alongside with Windows 8. I want to install Xubuntu again without Windows 8. Fresh installation, just Xubuntu. Will this increase this my performance?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a hard drive you should gain a little bit performance because Xubuntu would be installed on the first partition of the drive.

Answer (score 0):

No, an operating system that is not running should have no effect on performance.

You are best off destroying the Windows partition and removing the appropriate bootloader entries.